# When inflation occurs, why do bonds no longer get cheaper as they sell off?

Tags: bonds, inflation

I thought that inflation drove down bond prices in general, but I read in "The Invisible Hands" by Steven Drobny that it is only when inflation rises that government financing becomes a problem for bond markets, as that is when bonds no longer get cheaper as they sell off and nominal yields rise.

Comment: "as they sell off and nominal yields".  Did you forget a word between "and nominal"?